# Auth::user() - property or method "{username}" is not defined [Vue, Laravel]

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I use `<users-component  :user-name={{ Auth::user()->name }}></users-component>` inside my `example.blade.php` file (users-component is a Vue component) and inside of `users-component` I have a code:

```
<template> 
  <div>
   <button v-on:click="sendMessage">sendMessage()</button> 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      messageText: ''
    }
  },
  props: {
    userName: String
  },
  methods:{
    sendMessage(){
      this.$emit('messagesent', {
        message:this.messageText,
        user: {
          name: this.userName
        }
      });
      this.messageText = '';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

After click in my button "sendMessage()" I have an error:

> [Vue warn]:
>   Property or method "agnieszka" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive,
>   either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

How can I fix it?

Comment: where do you use `agnieszka`?

Comment: "agnieszka" is a logged user name, I think I am passing it to vue component in `<users-component  :user-name={{ Auth::user()->name }}></users-component>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous idea was a bit off, but the real issue is that You're binding the property `user-name` with `v-bind`'s shorthand. If You only want to provide a static value to the component, then just remove the `:` from the property name.

```
<users-component user-name="{{ Auth::user()->name }}"></users-component>
```

*td,dr*: Writing the property as `:user-name` the Vue template engine interprets this as below:

```
<users-component v-bind:user-name="{{ Auth::user()->name }}"></users-component>
```

and expects a variable, that has the name of `Auth::user()->name`.

Vue docs: [v-bind Shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here

```
methods:{
  sendMessage(){
    this.$emit('messagesent', {
      message:this.messageText,
      user: {
        name: this.userName
      }
    });
    this.messageText = '';
  }
}
```

and

```
<users-component user-name="{{ Auth::user()->name }}"></users-component>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it not helps.